# Selenium webdriver python, cannot find by value?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select one of three checkboxes on a page but the source code for them looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="Option" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="Option" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="Option" value="3">
```

So the only thing differentiating them is value, but there is no find_element_by_value. How would I go about switching between these 3 checkboxes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use xpath for identification of elements in such cases,

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='1']")
```

For a better understanding of how xpaths work, you can refer the below link
http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/

Answer (score 0):

I will use `cssSelector` to identify this. There is no mechanism to find the element by value. Use `find_element_by_css_selector` with the following selector. Refer the [api](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-elements)

```
input[value='3']
```

or, to be more precise

```
input[value='3'][type='radio']
```

Changing the value would definitely let you grab what you need.

Also, possible to use `xpath` with `find_element_by_xpath` for this

```
//input[@value='2']
```