# Click on button element based on its value in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

There is HTML code like below:

```
<input type="button" name="" value="back" onclick="window.history.back(1)" class="back-btn">
```

I want to click on it based on its value (back):

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('back')
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium webdriver python, cannot find by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610407/selenium-webdriver-python-cannot-find-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css_selector`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[value="back"]')
```

Or `xpath`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="back"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like you can select based on class name

```py
elements=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("back-btn")
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```

If you cant use class try selecting all input tags and filter by attribute

```py
elements=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")
for element in elements:
    if element.get_attribute("value")=="back":
        element.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but the Question is click based on value, not a class. There are some other buttons with the same class on the page.

Comment: ive added by value aswell

Answer (score 0):

This was easy for me

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("back").click()
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP wants to find the element based on the `value` attribute.

Comment: back  is the linked text defined in value attribute in this case. Hence there is no seperate text displayed for the button, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="" value="back" onclick="window.history.back(1)" class="back-btn">
```

Its an `<input>` element with the attribute *value* as *`back`*.

---

### Solution

Using the *value* attribute to click on the element you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='back']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='back']").click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='back']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='back']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```